# How to recalculate the css url paths when moving it to a different folder

Tags: php, css, relative-path

What is the best way to translate css so that it works in a different path. I've looked at a few different libraries (CrushCSS, minify) and they seem to only over this service along with compressing the files (which I don't want to do).

Is my best a regex? If so what are all the possible cases that I will need to handle?

For example, input: `/base/my.css`

```
@import url "../another/file.css"
#container {
    background: url('example/relative/path.png');
}
#container2 {
    background: url('/example/absolute/path.png');
}
```

Expected output: `/base/example/path/my.css`

```
@import url "../../../another/file.css"
#container {
    background: url('../relative/path.png');
}
#container2 {
    background: url('/example/absolute/path.png');
}
```

EDIT:

I'm not interested in "best practice" or ways to avoid this type of problem. I'm only interested in how to do the transformation so that the css remains correct in the new path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided that I would refactor some code from [Minify](https://github.com/mrclay/minify) to allow for the abstract css transformation I needed.

```
<?php

//This class is heavy borrowed from Minify_ImportProcessor

class CSSImporter
{

    static function changePaths( $content, $current_path, $target_path )
    {
        $current_path = rtrim( $current_path, "/" );
        $target_path = rtrim( $target_path, "/" );
        $current_path_slugs = explode( "/", $current_path );
        $target_path_slugs = explode( "/", $target_path );
        $smallest_count = min( count( $current_path_slugs ), count( $target_path_slugs ) );
        for( $i = 0; $i < $smallest_count && $current_path_slugs[$i] === $target_path_slugs[$i]; $i++ );
        $change_prefix = implode( "/", array_merge( array_fill( 0, count( $target_path_slugs ) - $i, ".." ), array_slice( $current_path_slugs, $i ) ) );
        if( strlen( $change_prefix ) > 0 ) $change_prefix .= "/";

        $content = preg_replace_callback(
            '/
            @import\\s+
            (?:url\\(\\s*)?     # maybe url(
            [\'"]?              # maybe quote
            (.*?)               # 1 = URI
            [\'"]?              # maybe end quote
            (?:\\s*\\))?        # maybe )
            ([a-zA-Z,\\s]*)?    # 2 = media list
            ;                   # end token
            /x',
            function( $m ) use ( $change_prefix ) {
                $url = $change_prefix.$m[1];
                $url = str_replace('/./', '/', $url);
                do {
                    $url = preg_replace('@/(?!\\.\\.?)[^/]+/\\.\\.@', '/', $url, 1, $changed);
                } while( $changed );
                return "@import url('$url'){$m[2]};";
            },
            $content
        );
        $content = preg_replace_callback(
            '/url\\(\\s*([^\\)\\s]+)\\s*\\)/',
            function( $m ) use ( $change_prefix ) {
                // $m[1] is either quoted or not
                $quote = ($m[1][0] === "'" || $m[1][0] === '"')
                    ? $m[1][0]
                    : '';
                $url = ($quote === '')
                    ? $m[1]
                    : substr($m[1], 1, strlen($m[1]) - 2);

                if( '/' !== $url[0] && strpos( $url, '//') === FALSE ) {
                    $url = $change_prefix.$url;
                    $url = str_replace('/./', '/', $url);
                    do {
                        $url = preg_replace('@/(?!\\.\\.?)[^/]+/\\.\\.@', '/', $url, 1, $changed);
                    } while( $changed );
                }
                return "url({$quote}{$url}{$quote})";
            },
            $content
        );
        return $content;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the best way would be to always use URLs relative to the root of your site.  /example/absolute/path.png will always work, no matter where you place the CSS file.

Comment: This is not an option as the css files already exist. I'm looking on a way of programmatically moving them while still keeping them valid.

Comment: Also in my case I can't use absolute paths as the site base isn't guaranteed  to be `/`.

Comment: They're always going to be /something.  In your own domain or subdomain they'll be relative to / and if you're in a subdirectory then they'll be /subdirectory.

Comment: In my case, the site is viewable from two different directories simultaneously (not my doing). So if I we're to use `url('/path')` for one, it would break the other reference. I *have* to use relative css for it to work.

Comment: In that case then I think you've only got two realistic options.  1) Create symlinks in location b that point to the files in location a, so both paths to the resource in question are valid, or b) replace the CSS file with a PHP script that outputs a CSS file with the paths recomputed as needed.  I'd recommend the former, as the latter will cause issues with caching the stylesheet.